# To CONCATENATE a set of columns in google spreadsheets using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used the following function to iterate CONCATENATE in the spreadsheets. However, it shows the following error

> Missing; before statement. (line 11, file "Code").

```
function iterate() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var startRow = 2; 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();   

  for (var i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++)
  {
    var result(i)  =                 =CONCATENATE("http://cdn.staticmb.com/mbphoto/property/original_images/",A(i),    "/  ",E(i), "/" ,C(i),"/",D(i)) ;

    var range = sheet.getRange("F2,F15");
    range.setValues(result(i));               
  }
}
```

Comment: could you describe what you really want to do ? what result are you expecting ? the syntax of your script is wrong and it makes it unclear what you try to get.

Comment: I don't believe this is a proper use case for a script. The formula should be entered directly and copy down or use an array formula if you want it to automatically extend. The error you received will only be the first of many. Your code has a number of problems that show a lack of understanding of  Google Apps scripts.

Comment: The specific error is because the Javascript parser is surprised to see a function call `result(i)` after the `var` keyword, and thinks it must be a new statement. But because the previous statement (`var`) wasn't complete (which it would have been if it was followed by `;`), it detects and reports that error.

Answer (score 1):

Besides several javascript syntax errors like those pointed out in comments, the biggest issue is that you are trying to use "=CONCATENATE" in javascript. Its not a javascript function, none of the sheet cell formulas are, those can only be used inside sheet cells. You need to code the concatenation using javascript functions or operators like `var a= b + "x" + d`. That cleared out it should be easy to code it or google for it. You are also using `result(i)` where apparently you want to use an array. Look up the correct syntax for creating and adding elements to an array in javascript.